# Twitter popup window remains open after login using https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

Tags: angularjs, laravel, satellizer

I'm using https://github.com/sahat/satellizer for social login features
Now, while login with twitter after login is done Pop up is not closing
Redirected url opens in same pop up
How to redirect it to main(parent) tab ??

Comment: Could you set up a Plunkr with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your twitter Redirect Url. That must be wrong. After correct url it will redirect to your page and close that popup.